# Why Invalidate Cache/Restart option causes android studio to build forever?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have done research and seems the **Invalidate cache/restart** option optimize build time. Adding new dependency in the gradle, made android studio stuck building for **3 hours** now. I restarted the project and performed **Invalidate cache/restart** option. Which made the project to restart but still the problem persists. Meaning **Gradle:Build model...** takes forever to build. I have restarted the project several times but seems the issue persist. Also, I have done and performed most of the searches **Why Gradle Build Process is Slow** seems none of them worked for me.

Comment: In android studio, look at the bottom, there should be a progress indicator, if there's more than one process, you'll see something like "X processes running". Click it, check to see if one of the is paused. I have experienced it many times that I would simply wait for nothing. Near the "waiting" process there was a "Play" button that I could simply click and then everything would work. As if it's paused on it's own for no apparent reason.

Comment: @DanBaruch It's only one process running in the background. **I have removed the new dependency I added and gradle seems to build properly**. But when I add the dependency again the gradle starts it's building persistence. I have a well connected internet 1Mbps.

Comment: Then all I can think of is that the library is very big or it's dependencies are very big.

Comment: Seems I have figured it out. The dependency needed a maven artifact which needs a url jetpack. I added the  `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` into the `build.gradle` at project level.